# Making soap bubble input selection (like in apple music)

Tags: flutter, dart

The goal is to develop a widget where I can pass an array of strings and it generates the soap bubbles like in the video, including the physics effect when you drag them around. Does anyone know how to implement a widget like this, are there any libraries that provide the physics for the bubbles?

Here is the video I am talking about: https://youtu.be/ydYah_BXt9A?t=29

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - ended up going with React Native and then embedding it into the flutter app
Here is an example project I found on GitHub that I used as foundation: [react-native-bubble-select](https://github.com/jesster2k10/react-native-bubble-select/tree/master/example)